# How to obfuscate an OAUTH fetch request credentials as much as possible?

Tags: javascript, security, oauth, client, credentials

**Disclaimer** : This is a conceptual/design question, but please I hope that the community will be open minded enough to let me post it, I've been struggling with this idea for a long time myself, and would really appreciate some experienced external thoughts on this matter.

I've built a non-attended non-interactive JS client that runs on the background in the form of a browser extension.

The major constraints is : non-interactive, which makes it to the best of my knowledge, near impossible to verify the authenticity of the client.

The JS client performs fetch a POST request against an OAUTH 2.0 API, utilizing for now a very classic hard-coded "not to be used in real life" client_credential model, where the client id and secret are directly inputted in the code.

As hard as i can think about this conceptual issue, turning this into a certificate based token claim will not increase the security of the situation, in fact quite the opposite as an attacker could still very easily get to the plugin source code, extract the certificate and impersonate the extension to send malicious packets.

So basically my go to idea for the moment is to obfuscate the whole fetch request including the "fetch" keyword itself to make it as hard as possible, and as inintelligible as possible for an ill intentioned user to get to the sensitive credentials.

To execute on this idea i had the following in mind for starters :

- Turn each letter of the body parameter names into the result of a function, so for instance :

  `"client_secret" = (f^-1 o f)(C) + (g^-1 o g)(L) + ... + (x^-1 o x)(S)`

So instead of writing "C" in the source code, i would have f("C") which would look like some complicated """hash""", for each letter.

The composition doesn't have to be an addition and can be split between multiple lines etc. to make it harder to distinguish what i'm really doing, but this is just to illustrate.

- The values of each parameter will follow a similar pattern where they would be stored into local files in the form of the result of a cipher chain. For example :

  `"client_id.value" = DES(AES(Blowfish(MycustomfunctionA(MycustomfunctionB...(client_id)))))`

Then there is the problem of the "fetch" keyword itself which will prompt the interest of any attacker, this for now i don't have a clear idea about as it would mean dynamically loading code into the same context as the already executing one, and it's starting to get a little bit out of hand at that point, but still interesting in a way ...

So yes this is basically where i'm heading right now, i am clearly not sure about what i'm doing and this is why i came to the pros to ask if there isn't some better way, more clever approach to this very problem ....

Thank you all for your patience / understanding.

Comment: If you code ends up out of your control on a client, and includes enough code to make the credentials usable from that client, then you cannot prevent somebody from gaining access to the secrets. The only way to do that is to keep things on your own secured server.

Comment: Yes i know this of course, but i can't help it, i can't get the user to interactively login so the script will have to come prepackaged with the necessary means to authenticate to the backend, this is why i need to make it hard to find, but maybe it's in vain. Maybe i should just focus on the backend more, and assume constant breach, which is already the case somewhat right now.

Comment: @Pointy I think you are more than right sir, i've been struggling with this idea for far too long, and i need to come to peace with the idea that in this kind of architecture, if the code is sent to the client, then i should assume that whoever's behind that client can and will send authenticated requests potentially malicious. It is the job of the backend to make sure that it is aware of this eventuality, and can manage it.

Comment: Yea I feel your pain, but the nature of the internet is that you cannot even be sure what the client software even *is*. A web browser? Maybe. But you don't *really* know.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts on that:

1. Obfuscation is not security. Someone would eventually figure out what you're doing with the code.
2. You obfuscate code that is sending HTTP requests. An attacker could just sniff the traffic that is going out of your extension. She would get all the information from there and doesn't even have to understand your code.
3. Maybe you should look at Dynamic Client Registration. Every browser extension instance would register as a separate client so you could more easily control what is going on (and e.g. block suspicious clients).

Essentially, you're right — you should treat all traffic incoming from your extension as potentially malicious, and the backend should address the issue accordingly.